# Ghostscript OS error "no such file or directory"

Tags: ghostscript, postscript

Trying to import an external PostScript file into another via the "run" command like so:

```
(
save
%showpage {} bind def
("E:/My Documents/Development/Visual Studio 2017/Projects/ITL/SphereITL/SphereITL/ReportITL2/SphereItl/4_postscript/graphs.ps") run
restore)
```

The directory and file are both correct. Tried double backslash format as well as forward slash, with and without quotes. Still get the error.

What am I missing?

---

Here's Ghostscript's output:

```
GSview 5.0 2012-01-17
GPL Ghostscript 9.52 (2020-03-19)
Copyright (C) 2020 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.
This software is supplied under the GNU AGPLv3 and comes with NO WARRANTY:
see the file COPYING for details.
Displaying DSC file E:/My Documents/Development/Visual Studio 2017/Projects/ITL/SphereITL/SphereITL/ReportITL2/SphereItl/4_postscript/TM-30_Test1.PS
Displaying page 1
Loading NimbusSans-Regular font from %rom%Resource/Font/NimbusSans-Regular... 4376704 2870251 3628128 2298817 2 done.
Loading NimbusMonoPS-Regular font from %rom%Resource/Font/NimbusMonoPS-Regular... 4442816 3088087 3729128 2389676 2 done.
Loading C059-Italic font from %rom%Resource/Font/C059-Italic... 4670528 3335974 3749328 2397028 2 done.
Displaying page 2
Displaying page 3
Displaying page 4
Displaying page 5
Error: /undefined in @
Operand stack:
   (\nsave\n%showpage {} bind def\n\("E:/My Documents/Development/Visual Studio 2017/Projects/ITL/SphereITL/SphereITL/ReportITL2/SphereItl/4_postscript/graphs.ps"\) run\nrestore)
Execution stack:
   %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   1990   1   3   %oparray_pop   1989   1   3   %oparray_pop   1977   1   3   %oparray_pop   1833   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   %errorexec_pop   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--
Dictionary stack:
   --dict:744/1123(ro)(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:179/200(L)--
Current allocation mode is local
Last OS error: No such file or directory

--- Begin offending input ---
%%Page: 5  5

%%BeginPageSetup



showHeader

showNVLAPLogo

showFooter

gsave

% Formatting definitions



[ /Courier

 0.133

 10.00

  0.65   9.45

 (ABSOLUTE)

  0

  0

 [

(REPORT NUMBER:    TM-30_Test1                                       Page 5 of 6)

(DATE:             07/26/13)

(PREPARED FOR:     APPALACHIAN LIGHTING SYSTEMS, INC.)

(CATALOG NUMBER:   SL5-02 )

()

] ] prlines



(

save

%showpage {} bind def

("E:/My Documents/Development/Visual Studio 2017/Projects/ITL/SphereITL/SphereITL/ReportITL2/SphereItl/4_postscript/graphs.ps") run

restore)



@%showpage




--- End offending input ---
file offset = 13167
gsapi_run_string_continue returns -101
```

Comment: ghostscript is saying this: page 5 Error: "/undefined in @" so remove the @. Please read the Adobe Blue book, Green Book and Red Book to learn some more PostScript.

Comment: Thanks - I did find that @ character and removed it - the file / directory error is resolved but I still can't get the external postscript file to display with the run command.

Answer (score 4):

Firstly you aren't using Ghostscript there, you are using GSView. Yes GSView uses Ghostscript, but it adds a bunch of 'stuff' which can make things a little harder.

Anyway, the reason you are having a problem is, almost certainly, because Ghostscript now (since 9.50) defaults to SAFER mode.

When running in SAFER mode the PostScript interpreter is not permitted to access the underlying file system. The `run` operator, obviously, needs to access the file system in order to execute the external PostScript program.

The Ghostscript executable does attempt to add any files which should obviously be permitted to the permitted access list. This includes (for example) the input file as specified on the command line.

This change was signalled for years before we made it, and was documented in the [release notes](https://www.ghostscript.com/doc/9.50/News.htm) for 9.50.

In order to run arbitrary PoostScript files you will need to either add `-dNOSAFER` to the Ghostscript command line, or specifically add the directory containing the file you want to run to the list of permitted read directories. This is documented under SAFER [here](https://www.ghostscript.com/doc/9.52/Use.htm#Other_parameters)

Comment: Ok - I'll check that out - thanks - I'm a c++ guy forced into having to take a look into some postscript, so grateful for the help...

Comment: Still unable to get this to work - perhaps not implemented correctly.
I tried cutting and pasting (what I thought was) the relevant part of the .PS file, and it partially works - paging back and forth in the master document forces the display to work, although not positioned the way I'd like. 

I'm wondering, though, if it's possible to embed a PDF in the master postscript file?

Comment: No, absolutely not. PostScript doesn't understand PDF at all, send a hybrid to a PostScript interpreter (like a printer) and it will throw you an error. If you're getting something out then its not the SAFER problem. There's nothing else I can suggest without seeing the PostScript program.

Comment: Ok - thanks Ken - would you be up for looking at the PS files?  I could send them to you - rather not post company proprietary material online...  I'd be most grateful for your insight and the knowledge I'd gain from it...

Comment: I can give it a try, certainly. You can send me mail at "ken at spamcop dot net" (yes, its a real address, if rather elderly). BTW its reaching the end of my day here (gone 5pm) so I may not get to it until tomorrow.

Comment: I was just experimenting with converting the ps files to jpeg and inserting the images into the master ps file but I get an invalid file access error.  I saw some posts about some mods to the gs command line to fix that. Unfortunately I don't think I can make use of it because the c++ program brings up the viewer via a ShellExecute command - the reason being that GhostView might not be the default viewer attached to the ps file type - could be Adobe Distiller.  Any thoughts? Thanks

Comment: Almost certainly it needs -dNOSAFER, I can't see any reason why a ShellExecute wouldn't work, you just need to add -dNOSAFER (or --permit-file-read=<path>) to the command line parameters. Argument 4 of the ShellExecute Win32 API IIRC. Oh that would be for GS, You can change the configuration of GSView though, there's a menu item somewhere that lets you add extra command line parameters. But if you just want JPEG out (though I'd recommend TIFF or PNG to avoid the artefacts of JPEG compression) you could just use Ghostscript directly, instead of using GSView as a wrapper around it.

Comment: Got the thing to work by setting the GhostView option "Safer" to off and the script to run the external files now display. I have one issue now to resolve:  there is significant whitespace around the first graphic and I haven't found a good way to programmatically remove it so that it can be resized without overlapping other page items like the header and footer.  Any thoughts?   Thanks in advance...

Comment: ...or even make the graphic fill the entire page?   
After manually cropping the PDF, pdf2ps seems to ignore that and retains the white space...

Comment: Try -dUseCropBox, by default Ghostscript uses the MediaBox, if your tool for manually cropping sets the CropBox then GS will just ignore it. You can also set the media size on the command line, set-dFIXEDMEDIA and use a BeginPage procedure to translate the content onto the origin of the media. But that's hard work and difficult to automate.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the quotes around the file name. They are not part of Postscript string syntax.

```
save
%showpage {} bind def
(E:/My Documents/Development/Visual Studio 2017/Projects/ITL/SphereITL/SphereITL/ReportITL2/SphereItl/4_postscript/graphs.ps) run 
restore
```